# TabLayoutMediator from kotlin to java

Tags: kotlin

I need to convert below code from kotlin to java,

```
TabLayoutMediator(pager_tab_layout, digital_pager) { tab, position ->}.attach()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the above initialization of `TabLayoutMediator` and the calling of `attach` method on that as below

```
new TabLayoutMediator(pagerTabLayout, digitalPager,
        new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
          @Override public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {}
        }).attach();
```

Or you can separate the initialization and method call separately as below

```
TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(pagerTabLayout, digitalPager,
        new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
          @Override public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {}
        });
tabLayoutMediator.attach();
```